# Android Gallery Theme_galleryItemBackground

Tags: android

The JavaDocs for the Android [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) widget, mention the following:

> The default values for the Gallery assume you will be using **Theme_galleryItemBackground** as the background for each View given to the Gallery from the Adapter. If you are not doing this, you may need to adjust some Gallery properties, such as the spacing.

However, I don't see anywhere within the Gallery code, or any of the ancestors, where any value like this is used.  So, I'm confused as to how this is actually used, and what it is even referring to.  Help?